# Header file for installed NuGet package not recognized in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, halide

I am trying to learn Halide by walking through the tutorials. I'm working in VS 15, and have added the NuGet package for Halide and added it as a reference to my project (as shown in the image). The NuGet tutorials I've watched seem to indicate that once I add the reference, VS should automatically recognize the header file of the project, but this is not happening. I've read all the stackoverflow questions related to this, and have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package, restarting VS, and have made sure the package is in the right project directory. I'm stuck--how do I reference Halide in Visual Studio?

[screenshot of VS15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcEq3.jpg)

I am new to StackOverflow, Halide, and Visual Studio, so I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you restart VS. after installation ?

Comment: Yup! I restarted VS and then my whole computer @Calips

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Header file for installed NuGet package not recognized in Visual Studio

This issue is related to the nuget package itself. That because this package is missing a `.targets` file to add the header file folder to the `AdditionalIncludeDirectories`.

When you open the `\packages` folder in the solution folder, and open the folder `Halide.1.0.0`, you will find there is no such file `Halide.targets` file in the build folder. If you install the another nuget package `glew`, you will find the `glew.targets` in the folder `..\build\native` with following code:

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>HAS_GLEW;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../..//build/native/include/;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <ResourceCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../..//build/native/include/;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ResourceCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

That the reason why the Header file not recognized by Visual Studio.

The workaround for this issue, you can manually add the path to the `AdditionalIncludeDirectories`:

Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories, add the `C:\Users\<UserName>\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\packages\Halide.1.0.0\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`

Hope this helps.