# CPack NuGet native library

Tags: c++, cmake, nuget-package, cpack, nuget-spec

I struggle to create a NuGet package from a native C++ library. For now, I have the following setup:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)
file(RELATIVE_PATH relDir
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH $ORIGIN $ORIGIN/${relDir})
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/doc/${PROJECT_NAME})

# ...other CMake config...

install(TARGETS MyLib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/mylib
)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME MyLib)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR Me)
# ...standard CPack variables...

if(WIN32)
    set(CPACK_NUGET_PACKAGE_TAGS "Native" "native")
    set(CPACK_GENERATOR ZIP;NuGet)
else()
    set(CPACK_GENERATOR TGZ)
endif()

include(CPack)
```

Then, I run `cmake --build . --target package` to package my lib, and CMake correctly generates a `.nupkg` file containing the `.lib` and `.h` files I want. But then, when I try to use the generated package in a C++/WinRT project, I cannot `#include` the packaged headers.

So I have the following questions :

- according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62321661/1488476) and [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory), the packaged files should follow a certain hierarchy. Do I need to change CMake `install()` paths?
- according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560792/header-file-for-installed-nuget-package-not-recognized-in-visual-studio), the reason I cannot find my headers is because I don't have any `.targets` file. Do I need to create one myself or is there a way to tell CPack to generate it?

Comment: Did you ever find answers to your questions?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I think this CPack generator doesn't work correctly (at least when I tried). I did manage to create a packet manually using configuration I found [here](https://shed.globalgraphics.com/2018/03/15/creating-a-native-c-nuget-package-for-the-mako-sdk/), [here](https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2020/03/05/azure-devops-nuget-npm-cpp/) [and here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/deep-dive-into-nuget-native-part-one/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the problem still exists, but for me it works with the CPack nuget generator.

In my library I'm doing the following for installation.
I mark the inculde headers as public

```
target_include_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/>)

set_target_properties(${LIBRARY_NAME}
    PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/>)
```

For installation

```
install(
    TARGETS ${LIBRARY_NAME}
    ARCHIVE  DESTINATION "lib"
    LIBRARY  DESTINATION "bin"
    RUNTIME  DESTINATION "bin"
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "include")
```

The headers can be included in an other C++/CLI project after installing the nuget package.

Comment: Did the above cmake rules create .targets for you inside nuget specs file? It didn't work for me, so checking.

Comment: The nuget spec file contains the ID of the main project, but no sub targets. I use nuget to install a native library in a MSVC CLI project. I also added MSBuild scrips to integrate the library in the MSVC CLI project for propper linking. The build scripts are also part of the nuget package and auto generated with cmake based on some rules